# Sane approach to build and deploy typescript/node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, typescript

I'm working on node.js app that is written in Typescript, which means it needs to be compiled to JS before running. As I'm coming from java/jvm background where you ship prebuilt package to server and it gets run there I'm a bit afraid of the way of deployment where you push code to git and it's being built/compiled on server first and then run.

I don't like it for two main reasons:

- dev dependencies need to be installed on server
- deployment depends on external resources availability (npm etc).

I found NAR https://github.com/h2non/nar which is more or less what I wanted but it has some drawbacks (doesn't work with some deps that have native extensions).

My question is: is there any other "sane" way of doing deployment node.js deployment than this risky combination of `npm install`  and `tsc` on server? Or should I let that sink in and do it that way?

To be honest I don't believe there are no more sane/reliable options for that.

Comment: Ok, now it seems to me that Dockerizing such app can be one pf the options. What do you think? Has anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do (but there are probably other perfectly valid approaches) is building your project locally (or on a CI service), and only deploy this built version when you consider it as valid (tests, etc.).

This way, if something bad happens, like npm that fails, or a compilation error, you don't deploy anything, and you have time to resolve the situation.

For example, I used to have a gulp task (but it can be anything else: Grunt, a simple npm script...) that clone a *production* repository and build the project into this directory.

That way, I can check that my build is valid. If it is, I make a new commit and push it to the *production* repo, that is served the way you need (on a Heroku instance for example).

**Pros**

- Clear separation of dev and non-dev dependencies
- Deployment only when you know that the build is valid
- No built files on source control on the *development* repository
- No "live" dependency on external tasks like `npm install` or `tsc` build

**Cons**

- You have two separated git repositories (one with the source code, one with the built version of your project)
- Production process is a little bit heavier than simply committing to master
- *(From comment)* Doesn't properly handle the case of npm package that relies on native extensions that have to be (re)built

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm thinking about (ideally) but there are some edge-cases like native module extensions (say one of my dependencies in `node_modules` has some native extensions) that I should "rebuild" on prod server. Also this is exactly what mentioned NAR tool does (but has some issues)

What is in your `production` repository? You say you build your app into this. Ah I see, you keep your built version in Git too.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't cover the case of native extensions. I didn't think about it, I will add it to the *cons* list.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other "sane" way of doing deployment node.js deployment than this risky combination of npm install and tsc on server

`package.json` + `npm install` + `tsc` *is the way to do it*. Nothing risky about it.

## More

Just use an `npm script` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript#npm-scripts

Comment: I'm using `npm script` but that's not an issue. Have you heard about not-so-old left-pad issue? Stories like this are one of my concerns, others are e.g. npm being down etc. I know, the combo you posted seems to be massively popular solution, but it just don't feel "safe" enough to me and I'm looking for alternatives. As I mentioned in my direct comment, Docker might be kind of solution here - prepare ready to drop-in, prebuilt container with all the deps. Will give it a try

Comment: @MichalOstruszka Docker definitely seems to be a safe way to do it. If you have a nice outcome, feel free to share it answering your own question.